# Google Speech to text Error Raspberry Pi - "Module object has no attribute RecognitionAudio"

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I have been following the quick start guide for google API speech to text conversion.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries

Whenever i try and run the sample python script i get an error stating that speech module has no attribute RecognitionAudio.  I have followed the tutorial and ran pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech.  What else could be wrong?

Here is the sample python code i am running.  it those the error at audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech


# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
gcs_uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.raw"

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code="en-US",
)

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

for result in response.results:
    print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

Comment: Hello, Joe, please provide us with some code of yours and mark the exact place where it's failing, to help us identify your problem. Thanks

Comment: Hey Grib,  I added some more detail about the code i am using

Comment: Maybe your problem has something to do with your python version. Can you please run `pip --version` and paste the output here?

Comment: pip 21.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Hmm, everything seems fine then. Are you running this code in virtualenv?